# Application that will connect speak with ADFS via SAML and OAuth

Tags: java, oauth, saml, adfs

I need to write java application that logs users via ADFS. ADFS can use SAML protocol or OAuth. Is it possible to configure my application to speak via both protocols, depending which protocol is used on the ADFS side? ANDF is I have in my application ~200 ADFS servers, does every ADFS server URL have the same signature as https://adfs.DOMAIN/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx, so I can unify it only by the domain name, or an ADFS server can have login URL like :
https://domain/adfsLogin.html, so it depends on server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016) can do SAML 2.0, WS-Federation and OpenID Connect / OAuth.

If you want your client to do all three, it needs three client side stacks.

Each ADFS has a federated service name e.g. login-company-adfs/adfs/ls/...

It should not be the domain name or the machine name.

There is no standard for this.